# Does Indexing small arrays of subdocuments in Mongodb affect performance?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

My Mongodb collection has this document structure:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    my_dict: {
        my_key: [
            {id: x, other_fields: other_values},
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
},
```

I need to update the array subdocuments very often, so an Index on the `id` field seems like a good idea. Still, I have many documents (millions) but my arrays inside them are small (max ~20 elements). Would it still improve performance a lot to index it, compared to the cost of indexing?

PS: I'm not using the `id` as a key (dict instead of an array), as I also often need to get the number of elements in "the array" (`$size` only works on arrays). I cannot use `count` as I am using Mongodb 3.2.

Followup question: If it would make a very big difference, I could instead use a dict like so:

```
{id: {others_fields: other_values}}
```

and store the size myself in a field. What I dislike about this is that I would need another field and update it myself (possible errors maybe, as I would need to use `$inc` each time I add/delete an item) instead of relying on "real" values. I would also have to manage the possibility that a key could be called `_my_size`, which would conflict with my logic. It would look then like this:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    my_dict: {
        my_key: {
            id: {other_fields: other_values},
            _my_size: 1
        },
    },
},
```

Still not sure which is best for performance. I will need to update the subdocument (with `id` field) a lot, as well as computing the `$size` a lot (maybe 1/10 of the calls to update).

Which Schema/Strategy would give me a better performance? Or even more important, would it actually make a big difference? (possibly thousands of calls per second)

---

Update example:

```
update(
    {_id: 1, my_dict.my_key.id: update_data_id},
    {$set: {my_dict.my_key: update_data}}
)
```

Getting the size example:

```
aggregate(
    {$match: {_id: 1}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, nb_of_sub_documents: {$size: $my_dict.my_key}}}
```

Comment: When you update/count the array, do you only update it for one particular document, or do you update many documents at once? If your update statement is directed toward a single document (e.g. `db.collection.update({_id:1}, {$set: {...}})`), then having the array indexed wouldn't make a difference, since you're not using it. Also, the 1st & 2nd design won't make much difference.

Comment: The update is on a single subdocument from the array. The correct subdocument to update is found using the ‘id’ field (not ‘_id’) of the subdocument inside the array.

Comment: Maybe an example of the update statement that you'll be using will be helpful.

Comment: Just added an example.

Comment: From the two examples, you don't need any additional index at all. In both cases, you're limiting the update/aggregation to a specific `_id`, which is indexed by default. Further, the two schema designs you posted earlier are not so different that performance would be affected. To confirm this, you can use `db.collection.explain().update(...)` or `db.collection.explain().aggregate(...)` and check if you see any stage marked as `COLLSCAN`. I don't think you will see any.